# I have a workflow that has worked until today - now it is erroring out

Tags: workflow, error

This is a newly created workflow, but was tested with over 100 transactions yesterday.  Today, the workflow will not run and returns this message:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(String
>   strName, Boolean bThrowException)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(String
>   strName)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.WorkflowPage.StrStatus(SPWorkflow
>   wf)     at
>   ASP._layouts_workflow_aspx._*Render*_control11(HtmlTextWriter __w,
>   Control parameterContainer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)     at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

HELP!  I've worked with Designer for several years and have never seen this before.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of this big long exception:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range. at
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(
```

Would imply that the process is trying to get an SPField object which is usually a field on a list or a content type. For this process it is using the internal name. The internal name of the field does not change. So basically your workflow is trying to find a field and is failing at it.

This field could be in a few places. It could be a field on the task list, the list that the workflow runs from, or the workflow history list. There could be other lists that this could be pulling from as well depending on what your workflow is doing but the ones I mention are the obvious ones.

You should take a look at all of these lists and make sure that any fields specified for all forms truly exist on all the lists and no one has deleted a field.

If there is any custom programming (though it sounds like you are using SharePoint designer) it is possible that the field is being accessed improperly through its display name though you are attempting to get it by internal name. This could potentially cause the workflow to break simply by renaming the field.

Lastly, if this is a SharePoint designer workflow, I would check that specific step and make sure you still have valid values for everything at the point in which its breaking. Make sure all variables you populating are pulling from valid fields in SharePoint, any forms you are calling (initiation forms, task forms, etc) all use real fields, and any emails you are sending with data use fields that still exist.

Take all the advice I have above and triple check it. The error means it can't find a field so there is either a missing field somewhere or you are trying to access a field incorrectly. If you supply more information we may be able to help more but with the limited knowledge of your workflow this is all I've got for now.

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your response. I will quadruple check all areas where these fields "collide'. BTW... just so you know what I am doing - I have created a separate list to receive items from a list tracker when the status changes to "complete". Thank you again!